# Save multiple objects serializers only if both of them are valid

Tags: django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

I have multiple serializers objects that comes from the request as json file.  I want to store them inside databases only if they are Valid (all of them must be VALID).

by default DJANGO save `tripserializer`. then if error occors in `imageserializer`,it keep `tripserializer` in database.

so how can save them only if they are valid both of them?

```
def post_images(trip_id,data):
      data['trip']=trip_id
      imageserializer = TripImageSerializer(data = data)
      if serializer.is_valid():
           imageserializer.save()
           return Response(status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
      return Response({'images':imageserializer.errors},status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        

class Trip_apiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset= Trip.objects.all()
    serializer_class=TripSerializer
    def post(self, request):
         data = request.data
         dataImg=data.pop('trip_images')
         if tripserializer.is_valid():
                instance = tripserializer.save()
                respo=post_images(instance.pk,dataImg)
                if respo.status_code==400: return respo
         return Response(tripserializer.errors, status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this is JSON :

```
{
     "id": 137,
     "trip_images": [
        {"image_title":"image1","image_order":1},
        {"image_title":"image2","image_order":2}
       ],
     "title": "dqw",
     "description": "nice",
     "start_date": "2022-02-08T12:00:00Z",
     "end_date": "2022-02-14T12:00:00Z",
}
```

Comment: You can use `TripImageSerializer` as a serializer for the `trip_images` field of `TripSerializer`. That way, the validation runs for the whole data

Comment: Can you give more details please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the validation to run for the whole json data, you can use `TripImageSerializer` as the serializer for the `trip_images` field of `TripSerializer`:

```py
class TripSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    trip_images = TripImageSerializer()
    # ...
```

so if you do:

```
serializer = TripSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid()
```

`is_valid()` wil then run the validations for `trip_images` as well.